# Do not show blank cells on excel graph

Tags: excel, graph

I have a problem solving something out in excel. I constantly have to manage financial informations from dozens of company as part of some startup acceleration programs.

In this context, as part of some analysis, I have to show, through graphs, the revenue information of the last twelve months of each company. However, some companies began operating 12 months ago, some other 8 months ago, and so on. Moreover, some companies report financial information each month, some others each quarter and so on.

However, if I select the same range of cells (same columns but different rows) for each company, the graphs will show the blank spaces when we don't have the monthly information of one company.

In this context, it is very inefficient to manually change the range of cells that each graph has to show for each company whenever we receive information from one company. Hence, I'm wondering if there is a way in which you could select a range of cells for a graph, but that the graph do not show the cells that are on blank, which could be some cells in the beginning or some cells at the end.

I'm attaching an image to explain more my problem, in which I point out with a red circle the blank cells that I don't want to have.

[image: Here]

Answer (score 2):

Directly copying @harrymc answer from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1403972).

There are various methods for avoiding the zeroes, none of them are perfect.
Below are a couple of such methods.

**Filtering the data set**

1. Select the data range.
2. On the *Data* tab, click *Filter* in the *Sort & Filter* group,
   to add a filter to all of the columns.
3. Click the drop-down arrow on the column's first row and uncheck `0`.
4. Click *OK* to filter the column, which will filter the entire row.
   Be sure to remove the filter when you're done.

**Replace 0s with NA()**

1. Select the data set
2. Click *Find & Select* in the *Editing* group on the *Home* tab and choose Replace,
   or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Enter `0` in *Find what*.
4. Enter `=NA()` in *Replace*
5. Click Options to display additional settings and
   check *Match entire cell contents*.
6. Click *Replace All*.
7. Click *Close* and *OK*.

For more information see the article
[How to suppress 0 values in an Excel chart](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-suppress-0-values-in-an-excel-chart/).

**My addition**

- One thing to note is that if these values are formulaic, then you can `N/A` them out via the formula bar. That would have the graph disregard the values.

Comment: If you're directly copying an answer from Super User, that's a sign that the original question *belongs on Super User*, not here, since Stack Overflow is for programming questions, which this is not. You might consider leaving a comment for OP with the Super User link, instead of copying an answer unnecessarily.

Comment: @BigBen there are other examples on here - I did one showing a different method, leave it to the OP to have a search, but it does belong here.

Comment: @SolarMike I fail to see how questions about constructing a chart are related to programming.

Comment: @BigBen do you think the Excel tag should be removed as it is too "low brow"? for "Real" Programmers?

Comment: @SolarMike from the Excel tag description: Only for questions on programming against Excel objects or files, or complex formula development. You may combine the Excel tag with VBA, VSTO, C#, VB.NET, PowerShell, OLE automation, and other programming related tags and questions if applicable. I fail to see your point. I also fail to see how this question is related to programming against Excel.